# Windows phone does not open inappbrowser after pdf download

Tags: 8.1

Into Windows Phone using Ionic Framework to create an App, i could not open a pdf file using inappbrowser, into Android it work´s fine.

On controller i do use :

```
$scope.showNewPdf = function() {
    var fileName = "somefile.pdf";
    var url = "http://someurl.com";
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Searching...'});
    pdfService.downloadPdf(url, fileName);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }
```

At the service i user request FileSystem and then window.open using _system for the opener parameter

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {fs.root.getDirectory( ...
window.open(fe.toURL(), '_system', 'location=no,toolbar=yes,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes');
```

Sometimes i just get no response at all, another i get the error message Download Error source -> null

I try to create a directory just for the downloads from my app

```
fs.root.getDirectory("MyappDirectory",
{   create: true         },
```

Is there a default directory for windows phone pdf downloads ? windows phone does not allow directory creation ?

The link to the full code is here http://plnkr.co/edit/SIX6dudoOXc713JWycA3

If you open a PDF after the download please just let me know how it is done.